# Using a checkbox with Material UI to change the boolean value of an attribute within redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form that is controlled by redux state and I need to use checkboxes that will change the value of certain attributes of state from true to false and back again. The way that I have it written, I can click the checkbox and it updates the attribute to true but when I try to click on it again, it doesn't uncheck and it doesn't change state.

Here is my form,

```
 import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {updateProfileForm,  setProfileForm} from '../actions/updateProfileActions'
import { update } from '../actions/currentUserActions'
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import { TimePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers"

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        NTXASN
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

const UpdateProfileForm =({updateFormData, updateProfileForm, update, history, currentUser, setProfileForm })=>  {
  const useUpdateProfileForm = () => {
    useEffect(()=> {
      setProfileForm(currentUser.attributes)
    }, [])
  }

  useUpdateProfileForm()
  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = event => {
    const {name, value } = event.target
    const updatedFormInfo = {
        ...updateFormData,
            [name]: value     
        }
    updateProfileForm(updatedFormInfo)
}

const handleBoolean = event => {
  const {name, value } = event.target
  console.log(event.target.checked)
  const updatedFormInfo = {
    ...updateFormData,
        [name]: !value
    }
    updateProfileForm(updatedFormInfo)
console.log(event.target.checked)
}

const handleSubmit = event =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    update(updateFormData, history)

}

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <EditIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Update your Driver Profile
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                name="name"
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="name"
                label="Name"
                autoFocus
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={updateFormData.name}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="email"
                label="Email Address"
                name="email"
                autoComplete="email"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={updateFormData.email}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                required
                fullWidth
                id="phone_number"
                label="Phone Number"
                name="phone_number"
                autoComplete="phone number"
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="tel"
                value={updateFormData.phone_number} 
              />
            </Grid>
        <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
          <FormLabel component="legend">Select Available Days</FormLabel>
            <FormGroup>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={updateFormData.monday} onChange={handleBoolean} name="monday" />}
                label="Monday"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={updateFormData.tuesday} onChange={handleBoolean} name="tuesday" />}
                label="Tuesday"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={updateFormData.wednesday} onChange={handleBoolean} name="wednesday" />}
                label="Wednesday"
              />
          </FormGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
          <FormLabel component="legend">-</FormLabel>
            <FormGroup>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={updateFormData.thursday} onChange={handleBoolean} name="thursday" />}
                label="Thursday"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={updateFormData.friday} onChange={handleBoolean} name="friday" />}
                label="Friday"
              />
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={updateFormData.saturday} onChange={handleBoolean} name="saturday" />}
                label="Saturday"
              />
          </FormGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
          <FormLabel component="legend">-</FormLabel>
            <FormGroup>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox checked={updateFormData.sunday} onChange={handleBoolean} name="sunday" />}
                label="Sunday"
              />
          </FormGroup>
        </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          <br/>
          <Grid>
            <TimePicker autoOk label="Hour Availability Lower Limit" value={updateFormData.availability_hours_lower} name="availability_hours_lower" onChange={handleChange}/>
            
            <TimePicker autoOk label="Hour Availability Upper Limit" value={updateFormData.availability_hours_lower} name="availability_hours_upper" onChange={handleChange}/>
          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Update Profile
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    
    return{
        currentUser: state.currentUser,
        updateFormData: state.updateProfile        
    }
 }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateProfileForm, update, setProfileForm})(UpdateProfileForm)
```

here are my actions

```
export const updateProfileForm = (formData) => {
    return {
        type: "UPDATE_PROFILE_FORM",
        formData: formData
    }
}

export const resetProfileForm = () => {
    return {
        type: "RESET_PROFILE_FORM",
    }
}

export const setProfileForm = (formData) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_PROFILE_FORM', 
        formData: formData
    }
}
```

here is my reducer

```
const initialState = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone_number: '',
    monday: false,
    tuesday: false,
    wednesday: false,
    thursday: false,
    friday: false,
    saturday: false,
    sunday: false,
    availability_hours_lower: '',
    availability_hours_upper: ''
}

const updateProfileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "UPDATE_PROFILE_FORM":
            console.log(action.formData)
            return action.formData
        case "RESET_SIGNUP_FORM":
            return initialState
        case "SET_PROFILE_FORM":
            return action.formData
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

export default updateProfileReducer
```

As I stated, right now when I click the check box it updates redux state from false to true and renders a checked box but when I try to uncheck the box, redux state is not updated and it does not uncheck the box. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `checked` attribute to check if the checkbox is on or not.

```js
const handleBoolean = (event) => {
  const { name, checked } = event.target
  updateProfileForm({
    ...updateFormData,
    [name]: checked,
  })
}
```

---

This is unrelated to the question but you can refactor your `handleChange` and `handleBoolean` functions by updating the reducer to apply the changes to the existing state.

```
const updateProfileReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_PROFILE_FORM':
      return { ...state, ...action.formData }
    // ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target
  updateProfileForm({
    [name]: value,
  })
}

const handleBoolean = (event) => {
  const { name, checked } = event.target
  updateProfileForm({
    [name]: checked,
  })
}
```

Btw, you don't even need to manage the form state in Redux since it's a local state. I would recommend using [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com) to simplify the code.

Comment: See when I put in checked, it doesn't do anything and doesn't update state at all

Comment: @morgancollado Weird. Can you share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) with the updated code?

Comment: Okay, I implemented what you said and while it does update the state to true but it still does not switch it back to false when I uncheck the box

Comment: Yes! I will create a sandbox, just a sec

Comment: here is the sandbox! https://codesandbox.io/live/mguy6zv

Comment: @morgancollado Looks like you've shared a URL to join a live session. Can you share the URL of the CodeSandbox you created instead?

Comment: Try this! https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cookies-n4epp

Comment: its giving me an error in the sandbox that I do not get when I run the server locally, so I'm not sure what is going on there.

Comment: @morgancollado Looks like the `handleBoolean` function still uses the `value` attribute. It should use `checked` instead.

Comment: Okay yup you are totally right. I changed it to `checked` and it works now! Thank you so much for your assistance and I will take a look at those other ways of implmenting it so that the code is simpler. Thanks a ton!!